# Which direction does `nodetool repair` go?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Let's say I log into a Cassandra node X and issue `nodetool repair`. Will I only repair the data residing on X? Or will I also automatically repair all other nodes that have replicas of what X holds (that is, reconsile data inconsistencies two-way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You repair all replicas.

> The nodetool repair command repairs inconsistencies across all of the replicas for a given range of data. Run repair in these situations:
>
> - As a best practice, you should schedule repairs weekly.
>     Note: If deletions never occur, you should still schedule regular repairs. Be aware that setting a column to null is a delete.
> - During node recovery. For example, when bringing a node back into the cluster after a failure.
> - On nodes containing data that is not read frequently.
> - To update data on a node that has been down.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/operations/ops_repair_nodes_c.html